# how to calculate the quotient of two permutation group

Tags: group-theory, math-software, maple, permutations

G/N

i guess G and N are both permutation group

however, i can not find command in maple to do quotient

there is really a quotient command in maple, however it is for polynomial

how about quotient for permutation group

could you give some steps to show how to calculate this quotient,
or where can find this quotient example

Comment: As far as I know, Maple has no group theory functionality. However, just plugging your permutations into a computer will teach you nothing! A better idea is to find an introductory book on group theory. Such a book will have a nice, worked example, and you should try an understand this as best as possible (this example might not be about permutation groups, but the concepts are identical).

Comment: i have several books, all of them do not have example to calculate quotient of group, i only know inverse, or power is just shift, and multiply is composition, how about quotient and intersection?

Comment: Which books do you have? For example, I have Fraleigh's book "A first course on abstract algebra". Chapter 2 is entitled "Homomorphisms and factor groups", and I found a quick worked example on p148 simply by looking through this chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple 17 got a new [GroupTheory](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/AddOns/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory) package.

It does not have a dedicated command for computing the quotient, but it may be done (with extra computation) by defining a custom group.

```
with(GroupTheory):

g1 := PermutationGroup({[[1,2]], [[1,2,3],[4,5]]});

                        g1 := ((12)(123)(45))

g2 := Subgroup({[[1,3,2], [4,5]]}, g1);

                          g2 := ((132)(45))


LeftCosets(g2,g1);

           {(()) . (((132)(45))), ((23)) . (((132)(45)))}

mult:=proc(c1,c2)
    return LeftCoset( Representative(c1) . Representative(c2), g2 );
end proc:

eq:=proc(c1,c2)
    return member( Representative(c1) . Representative(c2)^(-1), g2);
end proc:

inv := proc(c1)
    return LeftCoset( Representative(c1)^(-1), g2 );     
end proc:

operation_module := module() export `.` := mult;
                         export `/` := inv;
                         export `=` := eq;
                end module:

Q := Group(LeftCosets(g2,g1), operation_module);

             Q :=  < a custom group with 2 generators > 

## alternatively
#Q:=Group( LeftCosets(g2,g1), multiply = mult, inverse = inv, equals = eq );
#Q:=CustomGroup(LeftCosets(g2,g1), operation_module);
#Q:=CustomGroup(LeftCosets(g2,g1), multiply = mult, inverse = inv, equals = eq);

GroupOrder(Q);

                                  2

IdentifySmallGroup(Q);

                                2, 1

CayleyTable(Q);

                               [1  2]
                               [    ]
                               [2  1]

CayleyTableGroup(Q); # make it do all the work

              < a Cayley table group with 2 elements > 

PermutationGroup(%);

                               ((12))

PermutationGroup(Q);

                               ((12))
```

Comment: I want to say something like "I am unsure that telling people just starting in group theory how to get a computer to solve their problems is a good idea, as how will they learn without doing exercises?" but this is really very neat! I remember one of my friends in undergrad got maple to do basic operations on permutation groups, but it never quite got as developed as this. That said, there are dedicated programs for doing all this which are better, and are cheaper (e.g. free!).

Comment: Indeed, as @user1729 remarks, there are alternatives. For example, in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) the simplest syntax would look like `Group((1,2),(1,2,3)) / Group((1,2));`. One could also use `NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup` if more interested in keeping the connection between the group and the factorgroup.